Does the Boya BY-M1 microphone work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I'm planning to buy the Boya BY-M1 microphone for my YouTube channel, but before purchasing, I want to confirm if it works properly on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Has anyone used this microphone on Ubuntu, and were there any compatibility issues or additional configurations required? Thanks in advance!

I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic here. If you have an actual problem with a device, we can try to help with that.
